# .htaccess RewriteRule with special characters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make this RewriteRule work, although it doesn't for some odd reason. I'm thinking it might be the % signs that's screwing it up:

**`http://site.com/c%content_cc%/more-stuff/in/here`**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^c%content_cc%/(.*)$ ccontent_cc/$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to get it to rewrite to: **`http://site.com/ccontent_cc/more-stuff/in/here`**

when I use this tool and put in my rules it comes back stating it should rewrite properly.

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the browser sees the `%` sign in URLs often where it's used in [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). You can wrap the `%` characters in brackets and they're treated literally. Here we'll pull them from the `REQUEST_URI`.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c[%]content_cc[%]/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.* ccontent_cc/%1 [L]
```

If this is a redirect you should use the `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c[%]content_cc[%]/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.* ccontent_cc/%1 [R,L]
```

If it's a permanent redirect you should use `R=301`

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/c[%]content_cc[%]/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.* ccontent_cc/%1 [R=301,L]
```